# Discord.js - Delete messages without image

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way in Discord.js to delete all messages of a channel that didn't contain an image?
I have tried a lot of things but have come to no result. I am also not a Discord.js professional.

I'd appreciate some help.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

By default Discord cant determine the type of attachment, so is 1 way check ends of file type. You need to add `or` to allowed filetypes, and delete if message.attachments === 0, or filename ends not your allowed image format. 
The follow code allow message with jpg,png,gif , add other whats you need to handle.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if(message.attachments.size > 0) {
    let findImage = message.attachments.find(attachment => attachment.filename.endsWith('png') || attachment.filename.endsWith('jpg') || attachment.filename.endsWith('gif'))
    if (findImage === null) {
      message.delete();
        .catch(console.error)
    }
  } else {
    message.delete();
      .catch(console.error)
      }})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.  
And how do I make that into a command?  
You're supposed to put the command in a channel and then all non-images are deleted.

Comment: it's a command block already. If you need handle it in specific channel, so add channel validate to this code before attachment check 

`bot.on('message', message => {
if ( message.channel.id === "your channel ID") { 
 if(message.attachments.size > 0) { .......`