# How to delete picture in a channel | DJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to be able to delete an image sent automatically.
But ONLY the pictures and not all the attachments.

I'm currently using `message.attachments.size > 0`. But I know that removes all attachments; what I don't want!

```
    async execute(message, client) {
    if (!message.guild || message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL-ID' && message.attachments.size > 0) {
            message.delete()
    }
```

With my research, I came across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490855/discord-js-delete-messages-without-image) explaining that it was enough to add filters; `message.attachments.find(attachment => attachment.filename.endsWith('png') || attachment.filename.endsWith('jpg') || attachment.filename.endsWith('gif'))`

But for me it does not work; shows me an error, it does not seem to recognize the `.endsWith`

node version: 16.13.2 | npm version: 8.1.2

Thanks in advance ! ‍

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property called `filename` in a [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment). Instead, it has a [`name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=name) property which I believe you can use. So you just need to replace the `filename` property with `attachment.name`

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the tick mark beside it as it will show people that this solution worked for your problem